# Access sibling service from docker container's service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile, axios

I run Node image based docker container (Docker quickstart terminal from Windows)

```
FROM node:7.8.0
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

VOLUME /tmp
#copy server source /piu contains node server and /piu/client contains react+redux client
ADD piu /piu
ADD server_start.sh /

#clean windows \r char to make the .sh file real executable
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' server_start.sh

CMD ./server_start.sh

EXPOSE 3000 3009
```

I start Node client (on port 3000) and Node (express based) server (on 3009 port). Client accesses REST server via AJAX call.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    console.log('SERVER_URL=' + SERVER_URL); //the output is localhost:3009
    axios
        .get(SERVER_URL + '/posts')
        .then(res => {
            that.setState({pageInfo: res.data});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

It perfectly works from host (client accesses localhost:3009 and return results). And I can call :3009 and again have correct results.

But when I build and run docker image it fails.

```
docker run -p 3000-3009:3000-3009 --add-host="mongodb:192.168.12.151" MyDockerImage
```

`--add-host` is used to access mongo db running on host.

Server port 3009 is exposed so I have a working trick to call

```
192.168.99.100:3009 //the docker IP and exposed port
```

instead of `localhost:3009` but would be nice to let client access server directly inside the container.

How to specify localhost properly inside the docker container to access sibling service?

UPDATE

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the first process (server)
npm run start_docker --prefix piu &
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start my_first_process: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Start the second process (client)
npm run start --prefix piu/client
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start my_second_process: $status"
  exit $status
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few things you can do here

**Let other container run on network of other container**

```
docker run --net container:<id> MyDockerImage
```

Now your mongodb will be accessible on localhost. But the port needs to be exposed in the container whose network is used

**Create network yourself and use it**

```
docker network create myapps

docker run --name mongodb_service --net myapps mongodb
docker run -p 3000-3009:3000-3009 --net myapps MyDockerImage
```

Now inside your MyDockerImage, mongodb can be reached at mongodb_service

**Use docker compose**

You can use docker-compose to run both of them as a composition

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo: 
    image: mongodb
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000-3009:3000-3009"
```

And now in app mongodb will be reachable with name mongo

Comment: The problem is not mongodb at all. I successfully access mongo. Problem is accessing one service from another. Both are running in the same container. I tried docker-compose to have a separate imkage link for mongo but it does not matter. Suppose I have no mongo at all. All I need is to call localhost:3009 from localhost:3000 (both in the same container)

Comment: what is the content of `/server_start.sh`

Comment: The file is added

Comment: @StanislavL, now i understand your question well. The issue is that you do ajax call on localhost at another machine and that is not supposed to work. You need nginx and for this and then you need to use reverse proxy for nginx to handle incoming connections and the proxy it to 3000 or 3009 for you. Then people can refer to main nginx host by its IP and the localhost problem won't come. Another possibility is to generate the url based on current browser url. If browser url is  localhost:3000 then connect to localhost:3009, if it is 192.168.X.X:3000 then connect to API in 192.168.X.X:3009

Comment: In fact process2 (client)  tries to call process1 (server) internally. server should not be available outside the container. I access the same machine (inside the container). It works fine without docker. I run process1 and process2 on host and successfully call server from client.

Comment: Suppose on one server you run 2 web apps on different ports. App1 calls App2 by calling GET localhost:3009. Without docker it's fine. Now I place them into a docker container. I don't need app2 (server). App2 must be called by app1 internally and I see the result by calling app1 from outside.

Comment: Yes that is correct. There are two things in this if App1 calls app2 on the server side then just app1 can be exposed. But if app1 calls it through ajax in user browser then app2 needs to be exposed using nginx reverse proxy either on a subdomain or on another URL

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Will check how to create the reverse proxy.