# How to connect two NodeJS docker containers together?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker compose file in this file I create three containers, 1 mysql container and 2 NodeJS containers.

The 2 NodeJS containers connect properly to the mysql container.

However I am having a problem connecting the two NodeJS containers together I have added the service1 in the depends_on for the second one however in my javascript code I am not sure what to type for the url instead of localhost:3000 which I used before using docker

Comment: You can link the node.js container which calls the other one with "link" and adress it with the link-name or maybe better, you have to define them inside of a docker network

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access sibling service from docker container's service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074933/access-sibling-service-from-docker-containers-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compose services with `docker-compose`, the service name becomes host name when they're on the same network (which is default).

So from one container, you will make an api call to other container as

```
"http://servicename:port/"
```

Answer (score 3):

When you declare services in your `docker-compose`, you give them names. These names become the `hostnames` of the docker containers, if you dont manually reconfigure the network, I hope you dont.

So, having 2 services in yaml:
**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  node1:
    image: xxx

  node2:
    image: xxx
```

You just refer them as `node1` and `node2` like `ping node1` from `node2` for example